# Design effects (or variances) of sampling methods?

Tags: sampling, variance

Where I can find comparison of variances (or design effect) of different [sampling methods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sampling_methods#Sampling_methods)?

Same population, same sample size: I want to know which one has smaller variance than other; in simple random sampling, systematic sampling, stratified sampling, cluster sampling and so on.

Comment: Have you taken any sampling classes, or worked through any sampling books, like Lohr (2009, http://www.amazon.com/Sampling-Analysis-Advanced-Cengage-Learning/dp/0495105279), Kish (1995, http://www.amazon.com/Survey-Sampling-Wiley-Classics-Library/dp/0471109495), or Cochran (1977, http://www.amazon.com/Sampling-Techniques-3rd-William-Cochran/dp/047116240X/)? It looks like you are familiar with the main terms, but if you did have training in sampling methods, you'd know the answers already :)

Answer (score 1):

A population either does have or does not have a natural clustering structure (schools, classes, students), and/or list information for every unit (that you can use for stratification; geography or ), and that's what dictates feasibility of a particular sampling method. Generally, stratified samples have smaller variances; systematic samples may approach the efficiency of proportionate stratified samples if the list from which the stratified sample is taken is cleverly organized, but it is more difficult to estimate variances with them properly. Systematic samples are actually clustered samples constructed in such a way that each cluster is approximately as heterogeneous as the whole population; in practical situations, real clusters tend to be more homogeneous than the population, and efficiency losses are suffered.